# My Node.js backend hangs when I perform database updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm running a React/Node/MariaDB setup, where my Node acts as a getter and setter to my database depending on front end events. So I have React polling Node every 2 seconds to get a value called `selectorPos` or `selPos` in some cases. This value needs to be kept up to date with the database value, but also needs to be able to be changed by the GUI components. So I have a button press set to update the value in the database, then it would be read and updated upon the 2 second polling.

My solution works perfectly for a few button clicks. But seemingly randomly it will hang after a database write and nothing else works. Once I force stop the node server and restart, it rapid prints out a bunch of `console.log` statements I had set up for polling and writing, as if it had a backlog to catch up on, then it works again until another hang and reset.

I feel like there is something quite minor I am overlooking here. The code works, but it seems to get overloaded quite easily.

Here is my code:

React stuff:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> this.getSelPos(), 2000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)  
  }
  
  getSelPos() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/selector",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({SelectorPos: parseInt(response.data)});
      console.log("Selpos is" + selPos);
    });
  }

  setSelPos(i) {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/selector",  { position: i }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

 handleClick(i){
    this.setSelPos(i);
```

Node:

```
const express = require('express')
const db = require('./db')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
// GET
app.get('/selector', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.pool.query("select value from db.tags where tag='1006'");
        res.send(result[0].value.toString());
        console.log(result[0].value.toString());
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
// POST
app.post('/selector', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.pool.query("update db.tags set value = " + req.body.position.toString() + " where tag='1006'");
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});


 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Instead of `throw err;`, you may try to `console.log(err);`

Comment: there is no `res.send` on your post path for NodeJS backend